# Joining single column two tables in to another table with two columns and Converting in to Integer?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, temp

I have two #temp tables with single column I need to transfer both those columns into new #temp table by converting one column in to INT?

```
#ProductID
Pid
4
7
8
9
23
88


#Name
Name
tom
jerry
harry
jim
jack
jones
```

How can insert in to new temp table with two columns and change #ProductID column in to Int data type?

The new temp table should look like:

```
#Temp1
Pid     name

4        tom

7       jerry

8       harry

9        jim

23     jack

88      jones
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 4 goes with 'tom' and 7 goes with 'jerry' in your example and you have SQL Server 2005 or greater.  You'll have to use the ROW_NUMBER() function.

This is basically what you'll have to do.  Might be slightly off based on the sort of your two tables.

```
SELECT
    ProductID,
    name
INTO #Result
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Pid,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Fake) AS RowID
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Pid,
            1 AS Fake
        FROM #ProductID
    ) InnP
) P
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        Name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Fake) AS RowID
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Name,
            1 AS Fake
        FROM #Name
    ) InnP
) N ON N.RowID = P.RowID;
```

EDIT: If your original temp table wasn't of type INT then the final result would require 'CONVERT(INT, Pid) AS Pid'. I was assuming you also knew how to create a temp table, just in case you don't before the 'FROM' of your result you can add 'INTO #Whatever' or create your temp table ahead of time and 'INSERT INTO #Whatever'.

EDIT 2: Apparently ROW_NUMBER() doesn't allow you to sort by a constant so the query gets more complicated...

Comment: :Thanks iam new sqlbie

Answer (score 0):

if there is no sorting key in a table, there is no way to make sure that you can retrieve the information there by the same order that you inserted in.

I'll assume that you inserted the information in `#Name` in a given order that you want to keep for future usage. So to keep that order you should have an `identity column` in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE #Name 
(
     id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
     [Name] VARCHAR(100)
)
```

after that you'll be able to join both tables into one.

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT, Pid) AS nPid, [name]
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CONVERT(INT, Pid ) )as RN , Pid 
    FROM #ProductID) p
INNER JOIN #Name ON p.RN = id
```

the example in [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efd52/1/0) can't use temp tables due the nature of fiddle, but otherwise is exactly the as above.